# Limit footer height to 100px with Google responsive add

Tags: javascript, html, css, adsense

I have a website with a google map on it which I am trying to place a google ad at the bottom on a footer that can eventually be dismissed. Right now I am struggling with holding the height of the footer to 100px once I put a responsive ad sense ad in it.

I tried following the google Adsense api with this:

```
     <div class="footer" style="height:100px !important">

<style>
.example_responsive_1 { width: 320px; height: 100px; }
@media(min-width: 500px) { .example_responsive_1 { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
@media(min-width: 800px) { .example_responsive_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
</style>          
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Anchor Ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle example_responsive_1"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-3213091474519287"
     data-ad-slot="6029013039"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

        </div>
```

But it keeps jumping up much larger than 100px. You can see the code live here: https://www.seekadventure.net/adventureMap2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ads script appears to do two things:

- it overwrites your inline styling on your `.footer` with `height: auto !important`
- it contains inline styling on the add itself.

What you could do is place `!important` after each of your style declarations (for example:

```css
.example_responsive_1 { width: 320px; height: 100px !important; }
@media(min-width: 500px) { .example_responsive_1 { width: 468px; height: 60px!important; } }
@media(min-width: 800px) { .example_responsive_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px !important; } }
```

While this ***does*** solve the footer sizing problem, it creates a different one: displaying the adds in a page real-estate only `100px` tall - which appears to be the reason why the script overwrites the host element's `height` value in the first place.

One thing you could do to improve this is:

```
.example_responsive_1 {
  transform: scale(calc(10/28));
  transform-origin: top;
}
```

Another would be to make the footer's background transparent.

Comment: I do plan on making it transparent but I want to get the sizing of the ad right first.

Comment: I just tried adding important to all the lines like the top part of your answer says and that didn't change anything. I then tried adding the code for the .example in the second part of your answer and that just made the add small but not the footer>

Comment: @searay, what you call *"the top part of the answer"* should definitely have worked, because it does when I do it manually on the live page. I'm afraid I can't help you further without an actual [mcve]. Find a means for me (or anyone else, who might be able to help) to be able to test their potential solution against your code. The only way to do it right now is to make a Google Ads account. I won't through the trouble of setting one up just to answer a SO question. Besides, after finding a fix, without [mcve] the question won't be relevant anymore, which makes it somewhat selfish.

Comment: If you look at my page source I have the important tags there and it didn't work. I left the code in place for you to see. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: @searayman, It's `property: rule !important;`, not `property: rule; !important`. When you place a semicolon you tell the parser current rule is over. So the `!important` doesn't apply. It's simply invalid and therefore ignored.